# WPF: XAML Parse Exception was unhandled

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I familiarized myself in WinForms, and I am trying to learn some WPF stuff.

I am experiencing this XAML Parse Exception as the Window is initializing. Here are some investigation that I've got so far.

To start, I have 2 classes which named 'Question' and 'Answer'.

I got the error when I tried to initializes these 2 class like this:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}   

private string _firstName;

public string FirstName
{
    get { return _firstName; }
    set { _firstName = value; }
}

Question _question = new Question();
Answer _answer = new Answer();

private void MetroWindow_Initialized_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}

private void MetroWindow_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //some code here
}

private void btnStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //some code here
}
```

But when I tried to remove the initialization of Question and Answer, it runs okay.

BTW I am using MahApps.

Can somebody give me a hint with my problem? Thanks a lot!

[EDIT]

It say's

```
The invocation of the constructor on type 'Recitation_Game.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '4' and line position '9
```

You may want to look on my xaml here it is:

```
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="Recitation_Game.MainWindow" ShowIconOnTitleBar="true"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
        Title="Recitation Game" Height="350" Width="525" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" ResizeMode="NoResize" Initialized="MetroWindow_Initialized_1" Loaded="MetroWindow_Loaded_1">
    <Grid>
        <Rectangle Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="178" Margin="10,91,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="497" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
        <Label x:Name="lblWelcome" Content="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="30,109,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}" FontSize="14"/>
        <Label Content="Recitation Game" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="366,23,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="18">
            <Label.Foreground>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.MenuHighlightColorKey}}"/>
            </Label.Foreground>
        </Label>
        <Label Content="v. 01.00.00" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="432,57,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="14">
            <Label.Foreground>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.MenuHighlightColorKey}}"/>
            </Label.Foreground>
        </Label>
        <Button x:Name="btnStart" Content="Start Game" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="400,275,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="107" Click="btnStart_Click"/>
    </Grid>
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colours.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/FlatButton.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
</Controls:MetroWindow>
```

Thanks again!

Comment: XAML parse exception. C# code will not help. Post your XAML.

Comment: Also, post the specific XAML exception text - it usually has a line number

Comment: `I familiarized myself in WinForms, and I am trying to learn some WPF stuff.`. First Step: Forget everything you've ever learned in winforms. WPF requires a different mentality.

Comment: Also, there's no such thing as a `Form` in WPF. There are `Window`s, if you care.

Comment: Since you're coming from Windows Forms, you might want to look at: http://reedcopsey.com/series/windows-forms-to-mvvm/  It's a series I wrote about migrating to a WPF mindset from WinForms...

Comment: @ReedCopsey +200 if I could.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *suspect* the problem is that your XAML tries to use a `Window.Loaded` event handler, but there isn't one (at least not in the posted code).

This is on line 4 of the xaml:

```
 Loaded="MetroWindow_Loaded_1"
```

That being said, XAML Parse Exceptions don't provide a lot of information in their message.  However, you can inspect the `InnerException` of the exception, and typically get much more details about why the XAML parser failed.

Comment: i've got this event in the actual code behind 'MetroWindow_Loaded_1' sorry for not putting this. Please take a look at my edit, thanks!

Comment: @JRC Can you post the inner exception of your parse exception, then?

Comment: I've tried to set a breakpoint in InitializeComponent() but before it hit the breakpoint it already throws an error and 'No Source Available'

Comment: @JRC When you run, and receive the exception, you should be able to inspect the details at that point.  (Without a breakpoint)

Comment: Inner exception is 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException'. :(

Comment: @JRC Okay - so it's failing to load a file.  Are there exception details for that FileNotFoundException?  Note that this could also be due to an error in `Question` or `Answer`'s construction, as these will get created before that `InitializeComponent` call.

Comment: I got this now! Thanks Reed for making me realize how important this Inner exceptions are! I found this in the full details of the exception 'Could not find file 'D:\src\Folder\Folder2\bin\Debug\config.txt'.. thanks again for helping!

Comment: @JRC No problem - With XAML Exceptions, you always need to inspect the details inside the InnerExceptions -s ometimes many levels deep.